# ASP MVC 5 - Multiple partial views the user can independently change the order of

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have one page that multiple partial views can be or are pulled into.
Each individual user can select which partial views they want and in what order they want it.
Assuming we have the views they want and in what order they want it, how would i accomplish this?

Im fairly new to ASP MVC 5 and i cant find a way to accomplish this.

There may be multiple views as shown below, its currently hard coded how would i get these divs and partial views to dynamically change depending on weather or not the user wants then and in what order they should be shows

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="tools">
            <span class="icon fa fa-close"></span>
            <span class="icon fa fa-refresh"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div id="PieChart1">
                @Html.Action("PieChart1", new { pStartDate = 
                   @ViewBag.pStartDate, pEndDate = @ViewBag.pEndDate })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="tools">
            <span class="icon fa fa-close"></span>
            <span class="icon fa fa-refresh"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div id="PieChart2">
                @Html.Action("PieChart2", new { pStartDate = 
                   @ViewBag.pStartDate, pEndDate = @ViewBag.pEndDate })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="tools">
            <span class="icon fa fa-close"></span>
            <span class="icon fa fa-refresh"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div id="PieChart3">
                @Html.Action("PieChart3", new { pStartDate = 
                   @ViewBag.pStartDate, pEndDate = @ViewBag.pEndDate })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Do you have a code example we can look at?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the HTML and have tried using a foreach to loop through the data and change the action name based on a view bag variable but it seems too clunky.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the ordered list into the view, you can render the items in the correct order?

So in you controller, determine the sorting of the list (pseudo-code):

```
var orderedList = new List<string> { "PieChart2", "PieChart1", "PieChart3"};
return View("MyView", orderedList);
```

Now you can loop through that list in your MyView:

```
for (int i=0; i<Model.Count(); i++);
{
   RenderPartialView(Model[i]);
}
```